# IsNumeric throw FormatException while evaluating an object

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm working with visual studio 2008 developing software for windows CE 6.0, compact framework.

I'm having this "strange?" trouble with isNumeric method. Is there another better way to do this job? Why is getting me an exception? (two in facts...both of type FormatException)

Thank you

```
dim tmpStr as object = "Hello"
if isNumeric(tmpStr) then    // EXCEPTIONs on this line
    // It's a number
else
    // it's a string
end if
```

Comment: What is the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this using the code you provided on a Win CE 6 emulator. It falls into the `else` block.

Comment: it doesn't stuck software even if exception is not handled but it writes to console the two exceptions. How can I see stack trace if program doens't stuck on that point but go ahead? It goes in else statement to me too...but with 2 errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though the `FormatException` isn't listed in the documentation of `IsNumeric` it is indeed one of the exceptions that can be thrown.  The circumstances under which it will be thrown are

- Passed a string value
- The string doesn't have an `0x` or `&H` prefix

I couldn't find any rationale for this behavior though.  The only way I was even able to discern it was by digging through the implementation in reflector.

The best way to work around it seems to be to define a wrapper method

```
Module Utils
  Public Function IsNumericSafe(ByVal o As Object) As Boolean
    Try
      Return IsNumeric(o)
    Catch e As FormatException
      Return False
    End Try
  End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...perfect as stupid is to throw exception for this case..isn't it?

Comment: @RiccardoNeri it does seem really strange that an `IsNumeric` method would throw an exception on non-numeric input but it's what it is at this point.

Comment: it doesn't work :o it gives me same errors on the line of "isNumeric" inside try...catch.

Comment: @RiccardoNeri are you running this under the debugger?  If so just hit "continue" and you should be able to move past it.

Comment: Yes, I can go ahead without stuck software...using with debugger connected. I was only wondering if there is a better way to do it. Why this is not better? 
Return Regex.IsMatch(inputString, "^[0-9.]+$")

Comment: @RiccardoNeri that expression will still match non-numeric input: example `"....."` will match. There are some nice numeric regex's available via google that should work if you only care abotu simply numeric input.  The `IsNumeric` function though will almost always handle more cases than a regex you find online (conversion from `IConvertible` types, VB specific hex notation, etc ...)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this error is actually because CF doesn't contain a `TryParse` method. Another solution is to use a regular expression:

```
Public Function CheckIsNumeric(ByVal inputString As String) As Boolean
    Return Regex.IsMatch(inputString, "^[0-9 ]+$")
End Function
```

**EDIT**

Here's a more comprehensive regex that should match on any type of number:

```
Public Function IsNumeric(value As String) As Object

    'bool variable to hold the return value
    Dim match As Boolean

    'regula expression to match numeric values
    Dim pattern As String = "(^[-+]?\d+(,?\d*)*\.?\d*([Ee][-+]\d*)?$)|(^[-+]?\d?(,?\d*)*\.\d+([Ee][-+]\d*)?$)"

    'generate new Regulsr Exoression eith the pattern and a couple RegExOptions
    Dim regEx As New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)

    'tereny expresson to see if we have a match or not
    match = If(regEx.Match(value).Success, True, False)

    'return the match value (true or false)
    Return match

End Function
```

See this article for more details: http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2770.htm

Comment: This won't quite have the fidelity here the user is looking for.  `IsNumeric` deals with a host of scenarios besides integers, floating point numbers for example

Comment: Sorry Jared, why this isn't working right? It doesn't match numbers with decimal point, is it correct?

Comment: @RiccardoNeri the problem is that the `IsNumeric` function matches more than just raw numbers.  It will also match boolean expressions, objects that implement `IConvertible`, vb.net specific hex notation, etc ...  A regex won't ever have the full fidelity that the `IsNumeric` function has.